# How to perform vectorized operations in Python?

Tags: python, vectorization

I'm having an issue with my simple code that is suppose to be a mortgage calculator where all the rates from 0.03 to 0.18 are listed in a table. Here is my code and error.

```
l = 350000 #Loan amount
n = 30 #number of years for the loan
r = [0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18] #interest rate in decimal

n = n * 12
a = l
int1 = 12
u = [x / int1 for x in r]

D = (((u+1)**n)-1) /(u*(u+1)**n)

z = (a / D)
print(z)
```

---

```
File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    D = (((u+1)**n)-1) /(u*(u+1)**n)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Thanks

Comment: While computing D you are using `u` as an array in a vectorized fashion. Since `u` is a list, it won't work. To mae your code work, you should use `u = np.array([x / int1 for x in r])`

Comment: `u` is a list; what do you think `u + 1` should be? Or rather, what is `D` supposed to be, given a list of numbers?

Comment: Vanilla python data structures do not support vectorized operation. For vectorized operations, consider the `numpy` library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `u` is a list which cannot be used for vectorized operation which you are doing while computing `D`. You can convert your list to a NumPy array to make your code work.

```
u = np.array([x / int1 for x in r])
```

Alternatively, you can use a for loop or list comprehension to store `D` for each element of `u` as

```
D = [(((i+1)**n)-1) /(i*(i+1)**n) for i in u]
```

but this will again complain during `z = (a / D)` because `D` is still a list. Therefore, converting to array seems to be a convenient approach.

The another alternative answer is to compute `z` using list comprehension directly without involving extra variable `D`

```
z = [a / ((((i+1)**n)-1) /(i*(i+1)**n)) for i in u]
```

Comment: The last option worked perfectly! Looking at it now it seems like a very easy fix that I overlooked thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The current error you're facing is because u is a list (made via a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension)), and D tries to perform math operations between u (a list) and numbers. That won't work.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
u = np.array([x / int1 for x in r])
```

u will be a [NumPy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array), which allows you to do vector math with it. If you've never used the numpy module, it's an easy install using the [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) package manager. If it's not installed then

```
import numpy as np
```

will throw an error, and you will not be able to use a NumPy array. If you find yourself doing similar work often, it's likely worth the installation.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, you need to explain *why* it doesn't work. It would be helpful to the OP if you explained how to resolve the issue as well.

Comment: Let me know if that's sufficient

Answer (score 0):

If you make the initial list `r` a numpy array, every operation on it can be vectorised.

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint


l = 350000 #Loan amount
n = 30 #number of years for the loan
r = np.array([0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18]) #interest rate in decimal

n = n * 12
a = l
int1 = 12

u = r / int1  #vectorised
pprint(list(u))
print()
print()


D = (((u+1)**n)-1) /(u*(u+1)**n)  #vectorised

z = (a / D)  #vectorised
pprint(list(z))
print()
print()


# list comprehension alternative, to compare results.
z = [a / ((((i+1)**n)-1) /(i*(i+1)**n)) for i in u]
pprint(list(z))
print()
print()
```

Demo: https://trinket.io/python3/831425cc58